# version number in Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Hi I developed a simple Google App Engine in eclipse and I deployed it in to the Google App Engine. I came across the concept called version, the value mention in between the version tag in the `appengine-web.xml` will be used to store the project in the Google App Engine (if I use already existing version it will update),

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>gradlesampleweb</application>
    <version>2</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

[image: version in my project]

I had 2 version but now I am running 20170718t184037, I mention my version number as 2 in `appengine-web.xml` but the version in the App Engine is different.

my question is 
(1) what should I need to do (in code) show that my version number to be shown by the Google App Engine(if I mention new number as 500, this should my version number in the console page)? and 
(2) Even I have active with 2nd version, when ever I mention any one of the url (1-dot-domainname.appspot.com), (2-dot-domainname.appspot.com) it is taking to the same web page `20170718t184037` 2nd version, is it correct? (whenever I mention the 1st url it should not take me to the `20170718t184037` (2nd version) because my active version is [2-dot-domainname.appspot.com]) am I made mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy using the Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud app deploy`) or from within Eclipse using the [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse) (which uses the Cloud SDK under the hood), then the version in the `appengine-web.xml` is ignored:

```
$ gcloud app deploy —help
[…]
--version=VERSION, -v VERSION
        The version of the app that will be created or replaced by this
        deployment. If you do not specify a version, one will be generated for
        you.
[…]
```

CT4E prompts for the version in the deploy dialog.

> (1) what should I need to do (in code) show that my version number to be shown by the Google App Engine(if I mention new number as 500, this should my version number in the console page)?

If I understand correctly, see the [`ModuleService`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/package-summary) to get your current version.

> (2) Even I have active with 2nd version, when ever I mention any one of the url `1-dot-domainname.appspot.com`, `2-dot-domainname.appspot.com` it is taking to the same web page `20170718t184037` 2nd version, is it correct? (whenever I mention the 1st url it should not take me to the 20170718t184037 (2nd version) because my active version is `2-dot-domainname.appspot.com`) am I made mistake in my code?

Fetching one version shouldn't redirect you to another.  The *Cloud Console*'s [*Versions* page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) provides direct-access URLs for each version.